# Google Sheets "IFS expects arguments in pairs"

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get Google Sheets to identify a category in one column based on the value range in another column. In other words, the value will fall into one of 6 categories depending on the number. I'm trying to use the IFS formula below but its giving an error "IFS expects all arguments after position 0 to be in pairs. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

`=IFS(G4>80000, "HC", G4>64000, "Cat1", G4>32000, "Cat2", G4>16000, "Cat3", G4>8000, "Cat4", G4<8000, "NR")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spreadsheet is set to use comma as function argument separator, then formula is fine, so it's very likely that your spreadsheet is set to use semicolon as function argument separator.

Try to change the spreadsheet region to United States or another country that uses comma as function argument separator.

Comment: Thankyou. I used a semicolon and it worked right away. Appreciate your help :)